# Tiny_mce editor not showing in codigniter

Tags: codeigniter, tinymce, richtextbox

After one of my previous posts I received some good advice and I made the decision to use the rich text editor tiny_mce for making my blog, but again I am having a problem. I can't include the tiny_mce or after including it, it's not working. I set it up how the developers instruct you too, but no change to the normal textarea is happening. What should I do?

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
    <script>
      tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist,autosave",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak,restoredraft",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,

        // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
        content_css : "css/content.css",

        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
        template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",

        // Style formats
        style_formats : [
            {title : 'Bold text', inline : 'b'},
            {title : 'Red text', inline : 'span', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
            {title : 'Red header', block : 'h1', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
            {title : 'Example 1', inline : 'span', classes : 'example1'},
            {title : 'Example 2', inline : 'span', classes : 'example2'},
            {title : 'Table styles'},
            {title : 'Table row 1', selector : 'tr', classes : 'tablerow1'}
        ],

        formats : {
            alignleft : {selector : 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes : 'left'},
            aligncenter : {selector : 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes : 'center'},
            alignright : {selector : 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes : 'right'},
            alignfull : {selector : 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes : 'full'},
            bold : {inline : 'span', 'classes' : 'bold'},
            italic : {inline : 'span', 'classes' : 'italic'},
            underline : {inline : 'span', 'classes' : 'underline', exact : true},
            strikethrough : {inline : 'del'}
        },

        // Replace values for the template plugin
        template_replace_values : {
            username : "Some User",
            staffid : "991234"
        }
    });
        </script>
      </head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="somepage">
<textarea name="content" style="width:100%;height: 400px;">
&lt;p&gt;This is &lt;strong&gt;my text&lt;/strong&gt; that I &lt;strong&gt;use&lt;/strong&gt; for my example.&lt;/p&gt;
</textarea>

</form>
     </body>


</html>
```

Comment: how do you include the tiny_mce.js (i cannot see this in your code)? what errors do you get?

Comment: @Thariama it's just an copy paste error now i edited it.

Comment: Actually no error , but problem is including or not including the tiny_mce.js i am getting same text area. but i need rich text area as i am including tiny_mce @Thariama

Comment: hmm, difficult to say. at lease your tinymce init looks correct. can you check if the adress in <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
  really exists?

Comment: i have seen this are correct , i think there may be any problem for path , but i don't know how to solve them.                                      template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",  here is it neccessary to give any path?

Comment: hmm, depends. better check: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE_FAQ#Paths.2FURLs_are_incorrect.2C_I_want_absolute.2Frelative_URLs.3F

Comment: what happens if you log "tinyMCE" to your console? ( console.log(tinyMCE); )

Comment: I changed my editor ,now using ck editor . and it works. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just copied your code into a flat html file and it works fine.  My guess is the path to tiny_mce.js is wrong.

Questions: When you look at the source of your page, does the path to the tiny_mce.js file look right?  Is base_url()js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js really where your js file is located?   Can you open your site.com/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js file in a browser?

Also, are there competing javascript files?  Or are you using the JQuery version of tiny without preloading JQuery to your view?

Have you troubleshot the problem with Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools?

Comment: I changed my editor ,now using ck editor . and it works. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was puzzled as I use tinymce in other projects without problem. Having downloaded the latest version, it was the inclusion of *moxiemanager* in the plugins list of the sample provided by tinymce.com which prevented output. Removing this item from the list solved the problem. See [TinyMCE moxiemanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984522/tinymce-moxiemanager)