# TinyMCE moxiemanager

Tags: tinymce

I downloaded TinyMCE 4 and try to install it according to:
http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/basic.php or
http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php

It won't work unless I delete moxiemanager from plugins list. I tried to search for moxiemanager but couldn't find it. What is moxiemanager plugin? Can anyone direct me?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think, based upon the fact that at [TinyMCE download page](http://www.tinymce.com/download/download.php), it has MoxieManager and says "Buy Now", coupled with the fact that at [MoxieManager's website](http://www.moxiemanager.com/), it says you can view a demo or "get it now", and if you click ["Get it Now"](http://www.moxiemanager.com/getit/), you can buy it for a very expensive cost.

I was looking for the exact same when I saw your post via some Google-ing, when I realized I wasn't the only person having a problem. However, the wonders of Google (or at least its browser, since trying to do the same with Firefox and Firebug end up crashing the browser for me) pull off. You see, seeing as how TinyMCE has a working demo of its editor, which also calls from the MoxieManager plugin, it's a simple thing of locating TinyMCE's copy of the MoxieManager plugin, copying the code, and creating the directory and file on your webserver and pasting the JS into the file, reloading your editor, and all should work.

Thus, you can [find the MoxieManager Plugin here.](http://www.tinymce.com/js/moxiemanager/plugin.min.js)

Comment: Yes, but you need very complicated api.php, to get it fully working.

Comment: Just the JavaScript file in my link worked for me. Copy/paste it where you need it in your web directory and it should work just fine. No need for any api.php.

Comment: I meant, you can't use MoxieManager without api.php.

Comment: Hello, I tried to localize plugin.min.js and include it in my source. The script is called just fine, but moxiemanager plugin still not working. I don't see any difference appear in TinyMCE interface between adding moxiemanager and not, what's it for?

Comment: Ah, I found the difference, just ignore my question. Now I see what's it for, I don't think I need the moxiemanager. Thank you.

Comment: i get an error of 404 not found for api.php in moxiemanager folder. How will i fix this issue?

Comment: @Witold Kowelski . this was a great help. Thank you so much

Comment: Link in answer dosen't work (404) so this is valid link for Moximanger: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/moxiemanager/

Answer (score 22):

In basic example code, remove `moxiemanager` from `plugins`, so it will not look for this plugin and rest of the editor will work perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for a free alternative filemanager to use with the TinyMCE 4 editor, have a look at: [Responsive filemanager plugin](http://www.responsivefilemanager.com/)

Answer (score 3):

MoxieManager is a commercial software addon for TinyMCE (or other editors/systems), made by Moxiecode Systems AB. It is not included in the TinyMCE packages.

You can find more information about it on the official website.

http://www.moxiemanager.com

Answer (score 1):

MoxieManager - a good plugin for file and image manager for web. There were several difference version of this plugin for your needs (see: http://www.moxiemanager.com/documentation/index.php/Plugins)
Expecially a plugin for tinymce editor, based on java scrip and php. Its usefull for my simple editor with inserting image ability. Thanks for Alex answer and support.

Pham Thanh Phong

Answer (score 0):

MoxieManager is a plugin that allows you to upload images in tinymce editor. However this plugin is not supported in .Net server. So even if you download it and add it to your web app, still you will not get the functionality. One way is to write your own server side code for uploading images. 
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE3x:TinyMCE_FAQ

Comment: I don't believe this is correct anymore - there's is a .Net version available from the moxiemanager website http://www.moxiemanager.com/getit/buy.php?item=MMBNET

Comment: @Rob Thanks for sharing, I think it's new and my post was old.

Answer (score 0):

it won't work because moxiemanager plugin does not exist if you use the basic tinymce. if the plugin does not exist it's not gonna run tinymce plus moxiemanager is a paid plugin for the tinymce.