# TinyMCE not working - even with their example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

**ISSUE:**

I am attempting to use TinyMCE 4.0.12. But couldn't get it to work, it just makes my text areas disappear altogether.

**What i have done so far:**

I even copied their example code exactly from their page, and it doesn't even work with that.

I have extracted all of the files to "js/tinymce/"

Is there something obvious I am missing?

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/cg3e8/

**JS CODE:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste moxiemanager"
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
});
</script>
```

**HTML CODE:**

```
    <form method="post" action="somepage">
       <textarea name="content" style="width:100%"></textarea>
    </form>
```

Comment: are you using joomla? or what framework you are using the tynimce in?

Comment: Not using a framework, it's a design from scratch

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried your fiddle and I removed moxiemanager plugin, and It worked

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
plugins: [
    "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
    "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
    "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste "
],
toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter      alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
});
</script>

<form method="post" action="somepage">
    <textarea name="content" style="width:100%"></textarea>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cg3e8/1/

Looking on the google for it I discovered this question that It probably solves the issue

[TinyMCE moxiemanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984522/tinymce-moxiemanager)

Comment: Removing "Moxiemanager" from the plugin list fixed the problem, thanks!

Comment: not working, even with the jsfiddle you have mentioned

Comment: hey, apparently the js url changed, try here http://jsfiddle.net/cg3e8/270/

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use any local plugins (like MoxieManager for example) you need to load them using the new external_plugins option.

Answer (score -3):

```
<script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

Replace this `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>` part of your code with the  code above.

I hope it works !

Comment: Why should he do that? He says he has downloaded all relevant code locally onto his web server (at least, this is how I am understanding him).