# The usage of TinyMCE 4.1.4 in php page

Tags: php, html, tinymce

I'm trying to use TinyMCE 4.1.4  in my php page but I didn't succeed, I did include the path of TinyMCE but when I execute the script it gives me simple text area, I don't know what's the problem.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
      selector: "textarea"
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post">
      <textarea ></textarea>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you checked this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856547/tinymce-not-working-even-with-their-example

Comment: check your browser console. There will be an error in it. Please specify that error.

Comment: @BlankHead yes i did

Comment: whats the error showing in console

Comment: there might show that unable to find moxie manager

Comment: @BlankHead this is the error : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: give the resource name

Comment: @didyeg did you try my code?

Comment: @RakeshShetty yes but i want full option like include youtube video ... and i want it to work in my localhost without internet connection

Comment: so include your path according to that

Comment: 403 error is due to [What is 403 error](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=what+is+403+error)

Comment: he is setting up it on localhost,so he needs to purchase moxie manager.. Otherwise create a folder named moxiemanager in plugins directory and add some code.
Actually,it should be purchased

Comment: @RakeshShetty how , what do you mean

Comment: if that is the problem,I have the answer.so,first please specify which file you are missing..

Comment: in console,tell me which file they are showing the error

Comment: @VaisakhPc this is the file they are showing the error http://localhost/home3/menu/js/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js

Comment: are you using any frameworks?

Answer (score 0):

Works fine here **[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/64j7ahrq/)**

Try to include your code inside ready function before that include **[jQuery library](http://jquery.com/download/)** as well so your full code should be :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tinymce.cachefly.net/4.1/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea"
     });

    });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
<textarea ></textarea>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hey no need of jquery for tinymce to work..
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><!-- CDN hosted by Cachefly -->
<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.1/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
        tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});
</script>
</head>
<body>
        <textarea>Your content here.</textarea>
</body>
</html>

this also will work

Comment: I know jsfiddle is not showing any error so it may happen it is loading on DOM.

Comment: he is setting up it on localhost,so he needs to purchase moxie manager

Comment: Is he using moxie editor? i don't really see the line `plugins: "moxiemanager..`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're doing all the JS before the DOM has fully loaded.

```
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <textarea ></textarea>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "textarea"
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```